# How filter a dictionary in ansible based on other dictionary

Tags: filter, ansible

How to filter dictionary based on other dictionary by matching certain key/value pair. It works if dictionary_1 and dictionary_2 has same key/value pairs by using | difference(), but not working if number of key/value pairs are different.

```
- name: difference of two lists
  debug:
    var: my_dict_1 | difference(my_dict_2)
  register: output
```

My data sets are below

```
my_dict_1:
  - build: 0.0.15
    version: 15.1.4.1
    name: HD1.1
  - build: 0.0.10
    version: 15.1.2.1
    name: HD2.1
  - build: 0.0.20
    version: 15.1.3.1
    name: HD3.1
  - build: 0.0.30
    version: 16.1.3.1
    name: HD4.1
my_dict_2:
  - build: 0.0.15
    version: 15.1.4.1
  - build: 0.0.10
    version: 15.1.2.1
```

I am looking for output as below after comparing/removing my_dict_2 out of my_dict_1:

```
output:
  - build: 0.0.20
    version: 15.1.3.1
    name: HD3.1
  - build: 0.0.30
    version: 16.1.3.1
    name: HD4.1
```

Comment: How do you match items between those two dicts since they don't have the same keys (namely my_dict_2 is missing the `name`)?

Comment: (I might be nitpicking here, but your dictionaries are actually list, of dictionaries).

Comment: Yes. my_dict_2 doesn't have name: as that data comes is manually entered using a file. Where my_dict_1 comes from device. Yes it's a list of dictionary :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of indexes by the combination of the attributes *build* and *version*

```yaml
remove: "{{ my_dict_2|json_query('[].[build,version]')|
                      map('join', '_')|
                      list }}"
output: []
```

gives

```yaml
remove:
  - 0.0.15_15.1.4.1
  - 0.0.10_15.1.2.1
```

Then iterate the list and select items

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        output: "{{ output + [item] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_dict_1 }}"
      when: idx not in remove
      vars:
        idx: "{{ item.build }}_{{ item.version }}"
```

gives

```yaml
output:
  - build: 0.0.20
    name: HD3.1
    version: 15.1.3.1
  - build: 0.0.30
    name: HD4.1
    version: 16.1.3.1
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    my_dict_1:
      - build: 0.0.15
        version: 15.1.4.1
        name: HD1.1
      - build: 0.0.10
        version: 15.1.2.1
        name: HD2.1
      - build: 0.0.20
        version: 15.1.3.1
        name: HD3.1
      - build: 0.0.30
        version: 16.1.3.1
        name: HD4.1
    my_dict_2:
      - build: 0.0.15
        version: 15.1.4.1
      - build: 0.0.10
        version: 15.1.2.1
    remove: "{{ my_dict_2|json_query('[].[build,version]')|
                          map('join', '_')|
                          list }}"
    output: []

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        output: "{{ output + [item] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_dict_1 }}"
      when: idx not in remove
      vars:
        idx: "{{ item.build }}_{{ item.version }}"
    - debug:
        var: output
```