# Getting empty merged list when trying to merge two dict lists with multiple when conditions in Ansible

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

here are my two list -

listone -

```
list1": 
[
{
    "_ref": "LAB1/1/4094",
    "vlan_id": 12,
    "vlan_name": "test_vlan_1",
    "vlan_subnet": "192.168.1.0/28",
    "vlan_vrf": "vrf_1"
},
{
    "_ref": "LAB2/1/4094",
    "vlan_id": 12,
    "vlan_name": "test_vlan_1",
    "vlan_subnet": "192.168.2.0/28",
    "vlan_vrf": "vrf_1"
}
]
```

secondlist -

"list2":

```
[
{
    "_ref": "LAB1/1/4094",
    "vlan_id": "12",
    "vlan_name": "test_vlan_1",
    "vlan_ref": "vlan/ZG5zLnZsYW4kLmNvbS5pbmZvYmxveC5kbnMudmxhbl92aWV3JElORlJBTEFCLjEuNDA5NC4xMg:LAB1/test_vlan_1/12"
}
]
```

```
- name: merge lists final
  set_fact:
    merged_list: "{{ merged_list|default([]) + [ item[0] | union(item[1]) ] }}"
  when: item[0]._ref == item[1]._ref and item[0].vlan_id == item[1].vlan_id and item[0].vlan_name == item[1].vlan_name
  loop: "{{ query('nested', list1, list2) }}"
- name: print results
  debug:
    var: merged_list
```

I get output as:

```
TASK [print results] ***********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "merged_list": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

**desired output:** in below, if you notice list2 has a match with list1 first dict item so list2 item merged with list1 first item, in the final output i want merged with a match and also unmatched item of list1 which is second one.

"merged_list":

```
[
{
    "_ref": "LAB1/1/4094",
    "vlan_id": 12,
    "vlan_name": "test_vlan_1",
    "vlan_subnet": "192.168.1.0/28",
    "vlan_vrf": "vrf_1",
    "vlan_ref": "vlan/ZG5zLnZsYW4kLmNvbS5pbmZvYmxveC5kbnMudmxhbl92aWV3JElORlJBTEFCLjEuNDA5NC4xMg:LAB1/test_vlan_1/12"
},
{
    "_ref": "LAB2/1/4094",
    "vlan_id": 12,
    "vlan_name": "test_vlan_1",
    "vlan_subnet": "192.168.2.0/28",
    "vlan_vrf": "vrf_1"
}
]
```

i believe `when: item[0]._ref == item[1]._ref and item[0].vlan_id == item[1].vlan_id and item[0].vlan_name == item[1].vlan_name` condition is not working as i expected. Any suggestions/clue to make this work and get merged_list as the way i am looking for.

Comment: Avoid unnecessary complexity. See [mre].

Comment: I am missing the logic of this case. Why *vlan_ref* is missing in the second item of 'desired output'? The conditions are met both for the first and second items.

Comment: @VladimirBotka ```_ref``` is not matching with list2 ```_ref```  but rest of them matches (thats why i wanted to have three when conditions, all three has to match). what i want to achieve is if there is a match then merge list2 items with list1. in the end ```merge_list``` should have all items merged and other one which has no match.

Comment: I see. But, why is the second item included in 'desired output' when *_ref* is not matching?

Comment: @VladimirBotka i wanted matched and umatched in desired output. if there is a match in list1 then merge respective dict items of list2 with list 1 then , also i want other unmathced one to be printed in final list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in the lists are dictionaries. You need the filter *combine* to merge them. For example, the playbook below (simplified for testing)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    list1:
      - {_ref: ZG5, name: LAB1, vlan_id: 12, vlan_name: test_vlan_1}
      - {_ref: XXX, name: LAB2, vlan_id: 12, vlan_name: test_vlan_1}
      - {_ref: YYY, name: LAB3, vlan_id: 13, vlan_name: test_vlan_1}
    list2:
      - {_ref: ZG5, vlan_id: 12, vlan_name: test_vlan_1, vlan_ref: vlan/ZG5}
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        merged_list: "{{ merged_list|d([]) + [_item] }}"
      loop: "{{ query('nested', list1, list2) }}"
      vars:
        _conditions:
          - "{{ item.0._ref == item.1._ref }}"
          - "{{ item.0.vlan_id == item.1.vlan_id }}"
          - "{{ item.0.vlan_name == item.1.vlan_name }}"
        _item: "{{ _conditions is all|ternary(item.0|combine(item.1), item.0) }}"
    - debug:
        var: merged_list
```

gives

```yaml
merged_list:
  - {_ref: ZG5, name: LAB1, vlan_id: 12, vlan_name: test_vlan_1, vlan_ref: vlan/ZG5}
  - {_ref: XXX, name: LAB2, vlan_id: 12, vlan_name: test_vlan_1}
  - {_ref: YYY, name: LAB3, vlan_id: 13, vlan_name: test_vlan_1}
```

Comment: i have modified my code(removed some variables) in the question to to make it little more crisp. Please take a look. your answer didn't give my desired output. it gives only matching dict but i want unmatched too.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: i see a problem in above, as long as list2 has one item worked, but if it has more than one item output is misleading and i see different output. for example try adding one more item (like below) in list2 and run it` list2:
  - {_ref: ZG5, vlan_id: 12, vlan_name: test_vlan_1, vlan_ref: vlan/ZG5}
  - {_ref: XXX, vlan_id: 12, vlan_name: test_vlan_1, vlan_ref: vlan/ZG6}`

Comment: You should see a problem with your question in the first place. This is where *list2* has one item. When you decide what the case (more items in list2, expected result, ...) looks like [edit] the question and make the case [mre]. Then delete the comments.

Comment: one of your answer helped me , this is what i am exactly looking for. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72608616/how-filter-a-dictionary-in-ansible-based-on-other-dictionary .
your both answers helped me to solve my issue. thank you